# CSS transition animate without presetting property value

Tags: html, css, animation

Is it possible to animate an element using `CSS`, but without defining the initial state of the elements `CSS` property?

in some cases it seems to works - for example if I set the opacity to 0

```
.class{
   transition : all 1s ease-out;
}

.class-after{
   opacity : 0 // this works even without setting the initial opacity to 1
}
```

But... when trying to animate top,left,bottom,right properties I cannot seem to achieve the animation without presetting the property value

```
.class{
   transition : all 1s ease-out;
}

.class-after{
   top : 100px; // this doesn't work without .class-before
}

.class-before{
   position : relative;
   top: 0px; // setting the initial value will cause it to work
}
```

Is presetting the property value a must? which properties require presetting and which can be animated spontaneously?

Comment: by default `opacity : 1`

Comment: Yeah you can't transition from `auto` values. `left`, `right`, etc are `auto` by default, and you can't transition that. `opacity` is `1` by default, so it will transition without setting it initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties that have a **numeric default** can be animated without first instantiating their value.

The default of `top` is `top: auto;` (*[source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp)*), therefore you must declare a numeric value for it before animating, as CSS doesn't know how to transition from `auto` to *`number`*.

`opacity` on the other hand has a default of `opacity: 1` (*[source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp)*), therefore you can animate it without first setting it's value.

Answer (score 1):

When you check with Firebug/ChromeDevtools there are automatically set properties. `Opacity` for example will be default `1` since an invisible element isn't that useful.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

`Position` on the other hand does get the default value `auto`. And so the transition cant calculate any animation.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

in css by default `opacity` is `1` and `top, left, bottom, right` is work with `position` so you have to assign a value for them, by default they are `auto` like `top:auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

by default `opacity : 1`

> REF: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

and by default `top: auto`, what is the difference? here:

> `auto` Lets the browser calculate the top edge position. This is default
>
> REF: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp

Which means it is vary based on browser size. But opacity it is specific to 1 which allowed the animation to work from 1 to 0.